# Trouble with User Inputs in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm trying to code a simple calculator using Python (2) in Sublime Text that consists of asking the user for the first number, the operation, then the second number. However, every time I try to execute the code in Sublime, I can't get past the first user input.

```
num1 = int(raw_input("Enter your first number:"))
operation = raw_input("Enter your operation:")
num2 = int(raw_input("Enter your second number:"))
```

This works in IDLE, i.e. I hit enter after I enter a number and it prompts for an operation. Is there a different way to do this in Sublime?

Comment: Your script cannot read input from sublime text, it's just an out console!

Comment: You can use this https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Input

Answer (score 1):

Sublime text doesn't support input from the console, it's just an out console, anyways there's a way around, you can use [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL).
You get a full IDLE like console embedded right into the sublime text!

Quotting what you get:

> Launch python in local or remote(1) virtualenv.
>
> Quickly run selected script or launch PDB.
>
> Use SublimeText2 Python console with history and multiline input.

You can install it from package control(I guess you already have package control! If not get it from [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)).

Comment: Exactly this, I use this for my Python scripts also. Additional FYI: Package Control automatically keeps all your packages up to date, I strongly recommend you get it over manually installing SumlimeREPL.